# SetFrame Method doesn't work in ios8

Tags: ios

I am using table view with dynamic height.

```
-(void)ShowTblRoomType
 {

    // [self.tableView_roomType  setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
[self.tableView_roomType setFrame:CGRectMake(self.tableView_roomType.frame.origin.x, self.tableView_roomType.frame.origin.y, self.tableView_roomType.frame.size.width, self.tableView_roomType.rowHeight*self.roomtypeDetails.count)];
self.tableView_roomType.hidden = NO;

//set shadow to uitableview........
self.tableView_roomType.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.tableView_roomType.layer.cornerRadius = 8; // if you like rounded corners
self.tableView_roomType.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-15, 20);
self.tableView_roomType.layer.shadowRadius = 3;
self.tableView_roomType.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;

}
```

From here I am calling this method

```
- (IBAction)showRoomTypeDetails:(id)sender
   {

  if(self.tableView_roomType.hidden == NO){
    self.tableView_roomType.hidden = YES;
}else
{
    [self ShowTblRoomType];
}
// [self.view_reservation bringSubviewToFront:self.tableView_roomType];



 }
```

it works on below ios 8 but dosn't work on ios8.
on ios8 it shows only one cell.

Appreciate for help

Comment: when/where are you calling this method ? Are you sure this is called on UIThread ?

Comment: If you use  Auto Layout try to disable (uncheck) it.

Comment: I am not using auto layout

Comment: @VinodJadhav Are you sure that  `rowHeight` has the same value on iOS 8 ?
Did you implement `tableview:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` ?